# What kind changes can be found on Earth if we have a red giant as our star

Tags: biology, planets, science-fiction, physics, geography

Let's suppose we have a red giant as our star, what kind of climate would be on Earth and will there be any change in plant, animal and human life both physically and mentally. What about the geographical changes.

Comment: This sounds more like an astronomy question. Where is the worldbuilding element?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Akhil*! This is incredibly broad. An answer would need to write whole books to explore all changes to plants, animals, humans (especially on a mental level) and geography. Each of these topics alone would probably still be what we call "Too broad". Please [edit] your question to focus on a single answerable aspect. You can always ask more questions and for example link to the older ones later. I am voting to temporarily put this on hold until it's edited. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: @Secespitus Sure will keep that in mind and do accordingly

Comment: You mean besides the Earth being consumed in the photosphere of the star?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on Astronomy.SE.

Answer (score 5):

There would be no complex life, and probably no life at all. The red giant phase of stellar evolution only lasts for around a billion years, and any planet in the habitable zone before the red giant phase would no longer be habitable. So your alternative Earth would have been a frozen ice ball up until some time less than a billion years ago, which isn't long enough for complex life to evolve.

Comment: For context, it took 2-3 billion years to get from the first single-cell life forms to where humanity is now.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Can you tell me what kinds of stars supports life

Comment: @AkhilMankala The only kind that we _know_ supports life is G2, the spectral class of our sun. We think it likely that any sufficiently long-lived main sequence star can support life, which means classes F, G, K and M, but only while they're on the main sequence, not when they become giants.

Comment: In addition to longevity of the star, the activity level is also a major concern. Some stars generate a lot of flares and radiation. In many cases this would be enough to completely sterilize planets that would otherwise be habitable. Giant stars are likely to be among the worst culprits of this, so even with the billion years in the answer and a planet perfectly positioned, you still wouldn't be likely to have a usable planet with any life on it.